Best practice for waiting for tasks?
I'm writing a background program that waits for tasks, then does work.  (Specifically it's a golang program that reads tasks from a redis queue.)  When there are no tasks (queue is empty), I've got this running a for true {...} loop that repeatedly checks the queue.  Is this wasting CPU cycles, or is it unavoidable?  I think there are ways to push messages to a program, but I think on some level those mechanisms work by repeatedly checking anyway.  Because the program is only doing this one thing, I think I can rely on the OS to handle multiprocessing.  But still it feels odd to run a program around the clock to respond to occasional work.  What is best practice here?
Thank you!

If your program only needs to read from a queue and process the available messages, there shouldn't be any issues. However, if you also need to run another task simultaneously, you can execute this task in parallel so it doesn't block the main thread. You can use a WaitGroup or channels to manage synchronization and stop the other functions as needed.
